# Flutter Stream Pagination with ListView

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I encountered some strange behavior when trying to implement pagination with streams in flutter.
I used the bloc pattern to implement this, here is the code:

```
class TransferItemsListBloc {
  DataRepository _db;
  bool showIndicator = false;
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> documentList;
  int incrementSize;
  String searchString;
  DateTime startTime;

 static const int INCREMENT_SIZE = 10;

  BehaviorSubject<QuerySnapshot> transferItemController;

  TransferItemsListBloc() {
    transferItemController = BehaviorSubject<QuerySnapshot>();
    _db = locator<DataRepository>();
    startTime = DateTime.now();
  }


  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get transferItemStream => transferItemController.stream;

  Future<bool> fetchFirstList({String stringToBeSearchedFor}) async {
    incrementSize = INCREMENT_SIZE;

    print('fetchFirstList');

    if (stringToBeSearchedFor != null) {
      this.searchString = stringToBeSearchedFor.toLowerCase();
    } else {
      this.searchString = null;
    }

    documentList = _db.getTransferItemsOrderedByEndTimeInitial(
        incrementSize, startTime, searchString);

    documentList.forEach((element) {
      transferItemController.sink.add(element);
    });

    return true;
  }
```

The important part is the search String. When I pass a string to "FetchFirstList" I am filtering the results. If there is no string, no filter should be applied.

In the class where I show the results, I implemented it like so:

```
    Container(
              child: Expanded(
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: transferItemsListBloc.transferItemStream,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }

                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
                    }

                    List<Widget> transferItemsWidgets = [];

                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      print('Stream Builder');
                      print('length  of list: ${snapshot.data.docs.length}');

                      print(transferItemsListBloc.searchString);

                      for (QueryDocumentSnapshot qdSnap in snapshot.data.docs) {
                        if (qdSnap.data() != null) {
                          TransferItem item = TransferItem.fromFirebase(qdSnap);

                          if (item != null) {
                            transferItemsWidgets.add(
                                TransferItemInkwellWidget(transferItem: item));
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }

                    return transferItemsWidgets.length > 0
                        ? ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: transferItemsWidgets.length,
                            controller: scrollController,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return transferItemsWidgets[index];
                            })
                        : Center(child: Text('Keine Angebote verfügbar'));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

As you can see, the stream is plugged into a Streamcontroller and the output is displayed.

However, when the stream updates (a change/update in firebase occurs), the stream ignores the pagination and shows results without the filter applied. So every time an update occurs in Firebase, my ListView switches to the original list (without a searchString).

Why is this happening?

I suppose that it has something to do with this part here:

```
documentList = _db.getTransferItemsOrderedByEndTimeInitial(
        incrementSize, startTime, searchString);

    documentList.forEach((element) {
      transferItemController.sink.add(element);
    });
```

Do i have to close/drain a stream before adding new elements to the sink?

best regards,
Mario

Comment: Have you already looked at similar implementations in these links? https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-pagination-lazy-loading-from-streams-with-firestore-1f60ac06da75, https://medium.com/flutterdevs/pagination-in-flutter-with-firebase-firestore-96d6cc11aef2, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1chV50D5BVU&ab_channel=FilledStacks

Comment: Hi! Yes, I followed exactly this tutorial :-) But most of the tutorial use futures instead of streams. All I want is to implement pagination with a stream builder...and for some reason it doesn't work.